# Is it possible to open browser via LocalNotification immediatly?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I send a LocalNotification like this:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
notification.alertBody = @"Hello, open me";
notification.userInfo = @{@"TheKey": @"www.stackoverflow.com"};
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

and in AppDelegate I do use:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    NSURL *siteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[userInfo objectForKey:@"TheKey"]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:siteURL];
}
```

It opens the URL in new broswer window but it takes like 5-10 seconds for the app to take that action. Is it possible to open browser immediatly when LocalNotification is opened?

Comment: I don't think its possible because everything handled automatically.

Comment: And what is wrong with my question? why would anyone -1 it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS 7 and prior your approach would indeed be the only one. This is because `UILocalNotification` is only used to open your app, i.e. call the `AppDelegate`'s method `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`. So, the first place indeed for you to perform any actions would be that method.

However, with iOS 8 **interactive notifications** have been introduced. These allow the user to perform a specified action without opening the app. [image]

In the screenshot you see that the user just received a notification and now has the option to perform certain actions on it, without actually going back into the app. You can find a great tutorial on how to implement interactive notifications [here](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-notifications-with-notification-actions/)!

Comment: That interactive notifications have been introduced only in iOS 8.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that :/ It's a new feature that got announced during this year's WWDC in June...